# Starting server in MAMP gives me error R6034

Tags: apache, runtime-error, mamp

I have this problem with MAMP:

"Runtima Error!

Program C:\MAMP\bin\apache\httpd.exe

R6034

An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

I've tried many solutions to solve this that I've seen online:

- Unistalled and reinstalled MAMP
- Run the program as administrator
- bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVA 2800 in prompt in system32
- Press change on Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable in the control's panel
- Reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable downloaded from windows's site.

Any of the previous solutions work, is there a way to repair/avoid this error?

Comment: There are quite a few versions of MSVC Runtime libraries, and your Apache could have been compiled with only one of them, but which one? I always fond it best to download all of them. And also to download the 32bit and 64bit versions if you are on a 64bit version of windows

Comment: Yes, I re-installed all of them, from 2005 to 2019

Comment: You suggest to install 32bit version also? I've installed only 64bit version 'cause I'm on a 64bit PC

Comment: Is MAMP 64bit or 32bit? Windows 10 runs both 32 and 64 bit code and some bits of these tools tend to be left as 32 bit if the still work